# Unknown bash scripts running when terminal opens?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal

I am not exactly sure what's happening here - I open a terminal window on my mac and see the following:

```
Last login: Tue Jun 26 00:36:08 on ttys002
-bash: : command not found
-bash: : command not found
```

This seems to me like some file is being executed whenever I open a new terminal window, but I have no idea how I'd find this file.  Is there some list of files that run when terminal opens that I could find easily?  I'd love to know what is happening here (and how it came about in the first place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep Sorry $(grep -l Thank /etc/profile /etc/bash* ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.profile) /dev/null
```

And (when you are lucky) you will find the places where are these strange commands with `Thank` and `Sorry`.

It is possible although does these lines are produced during some command substitution.
In that case you will not find the strings. I would recommend then add `set -x` to `~/.bash_profile` to find the string that produces these messages.

Comment: If that Sorry is the output of a command, he won't find it this way

Comment: Although, you are right. It can be command substitution or something like this.

Comment: That found it, thank you! I have no idea how the text got into bash_profile, though.  Very strange.

Comment: This worked. I had '-bash: rt: command not found' every time I opened a terminal window. I opened my bash profile, and found a line that began with 'rt', and it was related to something I was doing a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Check `.bashrc`, `.profile` and `.bash_profile`. Specifically, I have a feeling you have a String marked with inverted commas, which is then being tried to execute

From the bash manual:

> When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-inter‐
>          active shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes  com‐
>          mands  from  the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading
>          that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>          in  that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
>          exists and is readable.

Comment: Thanks! I should have known that :)